# property of the javascript object is undefined

Tags: reactjs, object

I use React js. I have an object like this inside data.js. I write content because there is personal information.

```
const experience = {
    work: [
        {
            content
        },
        {
            content
        }
    ],
    event: [
        {
            content
        },
        {
            content
        },
        {
            content
        }
    ]
}
```

And then I import the data.js into experience.js and I want to check the data using console log. But the output is just empty object. When I try to access the data.work or data["work"] the output is undefined. I also try using JSON stringify. Does anyone know where did I go wrong? Is the way I access the property correct?

```
console.log("data : "+JSON.stringify(data.work));
```

Comment: how are you importing the object into the experience.js file?

Comment: Do you export data from `data.js.`?

Comment: Change the log to `JSON.stringify(data)` and post the result

Comment: sorry guys I forgot to export the data.js. Case is solved. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to export your experience object from data.js file

```
export const experience = { // your data here };
```

And then import experience object in experience.js file

```
import { experience } from './data.js'
```